# Playa with large number of entries +20,000

Tags: playa

I'm using a Channel Form to enable members to create/edit entries. One of the requirements is to select Relationships between entries. I have a channel containing over 20,000 government agencies and I want to related a few of these agencies (entries) to the entry being edited.

With 20,000+ entries, the standard EE relationship field is unmanageable when it has to be populated with this many entries.

Can Playa be configured to show no entries in the relationship until a member submits a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Playa has a useful setting to limit the number of entries that are loaded initially. This helps performance. The user can then search to find additional entries to choose from.

[image: Playa limit entries setting]